# Git submodules migration to another location

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I need to change submodules location on my Gitlab. I updated the submodule URL in my submodules (updating url in .gitmodules file), then I used commit and push to my working branch (no master branch). So, I tried to clone the super project from my working branches and clone the submodules using `` git submodule update --init --recursive``` but the modules are cloned from the master branch (with old url submodules).

Used command are:

```
git clone myRepo.git
git checkout myWorkingBranch
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Is there a way to clone directly from my working branch?
If I use `git checkout myWorkingBranch` in every submodules I get right submodules url.

I thinks that one way to solve my issue could be to merge working branch on master and maybe I could able to clone all right submodules but I prefer avoid this solution.

In the end, is it a good process to migrate submodules to another url?

Thanks

Comment: Submodules (which are just Git repositories) are not "cloned from a branch". They're just cloned. Submodule *branch names* are largely irrelevant: superproject commits list raw hash IDs and submodule checkout happens using the raw hash ID. Branch names play no part in this process.

Comment: As for moving from one URL to another: the URL from which any given submodule is to be cloned is stored in the `.gitmodules` file. This URL can be *relative to the superproject*. If it's not relative to the superproject, it's an absolute URL and hence fixed. No existing commit can ever be changed, so you'd have to "rewrite history" (make new commits that replace the old ones) to replace the URLs in all the existing, historical commits. You can easily provide a new URL in each new commit going forward, of course; each commit has a full snapshot of `.gitmodules`, just as all commits do.

Comment: All in all, it sounds like you want to make one new `master`-branch commit in which the `.gitmodules` file is updated to contain new (absolute or relative-to-superproject) URLs. A recursive clone will then use the URLs in this particular commit to run the `git clone` process for each submodule. Alternatively, you can avoid recursive clone in the first place, so that you have more control.